# GPUImage won't compile on iOS 12

Tags: cocoa, opengl-es, gpuimage, ios12

I have these errors:

1. `Cocoa.h File Not Found (in GPUImageView.h)`
2. `Unknown Type Name: **NSOpenGLContext, CVOpenGLESTextureCacheRef (GPUImageContext)`

Now, I tried to fix all these errors, but ended up making things worse.

I know OpenGL ES is deprecated in iOS 12, but as I understand deprecation, it should still be working for the moment, right?

For error #1, I don't understand what's a MAC OS framework (cocoa.h) doing in here (some of the references are not surrounded with #IFDEF MAC_OS statements).

As for error #2, these types are defined within the AppKit framework (also a MAC_OS framework, not an iOS framework).

I have considered switching to GPUImage2, but it's a ton of work as it's not as easy as swapping the frameworks, I'll have a lot of code to rewrite. I also see Brad Larson (the semi-God behind this framework) has already started working on GPUImage3 which will use Metal instead of OpenGL ES but it's still work-in-progress but it won't be a simple swap from GPUImage v1 to GPUImage v3.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I found a way to fix it. Maybe it will help someone with the same problem. The GPUImage main folder contains the iOS and the MAC projects.

Go to the **framework** folder, and delete the **GPUImageMac.xcodeproj** file.

Then go to the **Source** folder located within the **framework** folder, and delete the whole folder named **Mac**.

Clean your project and rebuild. Voilà!

Good luck!

Comment: In addition to "Clean" I had to "Clean build folder" and then restart XCode.  Thank you!